# Index is out of bounds when training a CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tflearn

So I have gathered a dataset of 100,000 inputs which consist of in-game frames (element [0]) and movements by the player (element [1]) (W, A, D). This dataset will be used to train a convolutional neural network, so an "AI" would be able to navigate throughout the environment on its own. The dataset is then shuffled, in order to balance it, to avoide having a biased-trained CNN.

However I met this error when trying to execute the training process, which is:

```
---------------------------------Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python64\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Python64\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Python64\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
File "C:\Python64\lib\site-packages\tflearn\data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
File "C:\Python64\lib\site-packages\tflearn\utils.py", line 187, in slice_array
return X[start]
IndexError: index 39977 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 17512
```

I have checked on the web, and most people said that it could be a loop iteration error (which may be obvious), however even after trying to iterate until the end of the array (using the len() function), this error is still displayed.

Please find my code here:

```
import numpy as np
from alexnetCNN import alexnet

WIDTH = 80
HEIGHT = 60
#learning rate
LR = 1e-3
EPOCHS = 8
MODEL_NAME = 'prototype-movement-{}-{}-{}-epochs.model'.format(LR, 'alexnet', EPOCHS)

model = alexnet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, LR)

train_data = np.load('E:\\Dataset\\training_data_balanced.npy')

train = train_data[:-800]
test = train_data[-800:]

#feature sets
#0 element refers to the frames recorded in the training set
#reshape gives a new shape to an array without changing its data
#--https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)

#labels
#1 element refers to the movements of the player such as W, A, D
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,WIDTH,HEIGHT,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

#sample testing
#-- The following method (model.fit) seems to be executing the mentioned error
model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=EPOCHS, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
    snapshot_step=800, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

# tensorboard --logdir=foo:C:/Python64/myScripts/modelLog

#when fitting is done, save the model
model.save(MODEL_NAME)
```

As I said in the commented line, the `model.fit()` method seems to be executing the error. Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: No way to reproduce the error without the data and quite hard to tell what's wrong from generic tf code.

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos thank you for your reply. You have quite the point here, and after some debugging I have found that the `.reshape()` method was transposing the matrix, thus causing it to not being matched. Also when I do `print(train.shape)` it brings up the following answer: `(17278, 1, 3)`. If multiplied, this is the same number that the error displays which is: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 51834 into shape (80,60,1)`. 

My apologies for putting few information since I am still learning. Do you have any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about it. So is your input then images of 3 channels and 17278 pixels? If so, keep in mind that the reshape function does not work like resizing an image, but instead rearranges the elements around (so the output has as many elements as the input). As a sidenote, when adding/changing information it's preferred to edit the original post and notify people with a comment rather than actually adding the extra information on comments. That way people can understand the question more easily and potentially help you or themselves faster without having to look at a lengthy conversation.